# Why doesn't this.props.children.map work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have written this code in several other components but can't seem to understand why this isn't working.

```js
{
    this.props.children.map(function(child) {
        return <li>{child}</li>
    })
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Define "isn't working".

Comment: You don't assign result of this call anywhere. So it "works" but you don't check if it does.

Comment: It returns `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

Comment: Well, your `this.props.children` is not an array then (or not some other object that has `map` attribute)

Comment: Have you instead tried: `React.Children.map`? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`this.props.children` is an opaque data structure. It can be either an array or a single element. In your case, `this.props.children` is probably a single element, which is why the `.map()` method is undefined.

You should use the [`React.Children` API](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren) when manipulating the `children` prop.

See also [Type of the Children props](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/children-props-type.html).

---

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You can bypass this problem by ...spread operator
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

```
[...this.props.children].map(function(elem) {
    console.log(elem);
});
```

Comment: This answer is not correct. This will result in a runtime error when `children` is no array; and when children is already an array spreading it into a newly created array is a useless activity and you could have called `.map()` directly on `children`.

Comment: Element.children is HTMLCollection and HTMLCollection is array-like object similar to arguments so HTMLCollection don't have map method directly, and that is why I first convert it to array.