# How to fix this.state.*.map is not a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to export one row from component, but don't understand where is the problem

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class TableRow extends Component {
state = {
    row: []
};

componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({row: this.props.children});
}

render() {
    return this.state.row.map((el,i) => {
        return (<tr>{el}</tr>)
    })
}
}

 export default TableRow;
```

this.state.row.map is not a function exception

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: this.state.row.map is not a function exception

Comment: this.setState({row: this.props.children}); this line it will overridte array defination to object or undefined

Comment: You need to put your state to a constructor and then use the "state" as ths.state, or just delete "this" from this.state.row.map and it will work

Comment: Look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29464577/why-doesnt-this-props-children-map-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem likely comes from how you are passing the rows to your component. Using the following syntax, your component will work perfectly :

```
<TableRow>
    {['Am row', 'haha', 'yes', 'another row']}
</TableRow>
```

I also changed `componentWillMount` which is deprecated to `componentDidMount`.

Working example :

```js
class TableRow extends React.Component {
    state = {
        row: []
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ row: this.props.children });
    }

    render() {
        return this.state.row.map((el, i) => <tr>{el}</tr>)
    }
}

const App = () => (
    <TableRow>
        {['Am row', 'haha', 'yes', 'another row']}
    </TableRow>
)

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
```

However, I do not see any reason for you to use a stateful component, you could take the values directly from your props.

The `TableRow` can be reduced to a single line for the exact same behavior :

```
const TableRow = ({ children }) => children.map(el => <tr key={el}>{el}</tr>)
```

Example :

```js
const TableRow = ({ children }) => children.map(el => <tr key={el}>{el}</tr>)

const App = () => (
    <TableRow>
        {['Am row', 'haha', 'yes', 'another row']}
    </TableRow>
)

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanations, it helps a lot for understand

Answer (score 0):

componentWillMount is considered legacy. It is called before render so it leads to your problems. Btw, you should set state on componentDidMount instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the row to be converted to state, this is a typical [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) issue. This way you do not trigger a double state change at the beginning, but your state will immediately contain the desired data. Otherwise simply render the data from props directly and convert your component to a [functional component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).

Answer (score -1):

The problem is actually that you're setting row to children (at componentWillMount), and you have no way of knowing if children will be an array, a single element, or undefined (no children).

React has a [helper](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren) to handle the typing of children, that allows you to just do:

```
render() {
  return React.Children.map(this.state.row, (el,i) => {
    return (<tr>{el}</tr>)
  }) || false
}
```

On the other hand, it's usually [not recommended](https://codeburst.io/how-to-not-react-common-anti-patterns-and-gotchas-in-react-40141fe0dcd#cbc8) to copy props to state unless you're just seeding some initial state that will later be modified. You can just access props from render too.