# Component for TransitionGroup

Tags: reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I'm trying to create a reuseable component for `<TransitionGroup>` but not sure where to place the `{children}`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';

const TransitionFade = ({ children }) => {

    return(
        <TransitionGroup>
            <CSSTransition in={true} appear={true} timeout={700} classNames="fade">
                {children}
            </CSSTransition>
        </TransitionGroup>
    );

}

export default TransitionFade;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably don't understand your question 100% (it could include more detail), but perhaps you were looking for something like this, i.e., use the fade effect on each child separately, not just as a whole?

```js
import React from 'react';
import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';

const TransitionFade = ({ children }) => {
  return(
    <TransitionGroup>
      { React.Children.map(children, child => 
          (<CSSTransition in={true} appear={true} timeout={700} classNames="fade">
            {child}
          </CSSTransition>)
        )
      }
    </TransitionGroup>
  );

}

export default TransitionFade;
```

Seems like a neat idea, since there are many contexts in which one would like to add or remove children from a list or similar. I might start using this already.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but `children.map()` doesn't work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29464577/why-doesnt-this-props-children-map-work